# How to animate an array of images in iOS

Tags: ios, image, animation

I have an array of images that I want a UIImageView to animate

I know how to do this with this method:

```
[myImageView setAnimationImages:myImageArray];
[myImageView setAnimationDuration:.7];
[myImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
[myImageView startAnimating];
```

However I want to use a different method. I want to do this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     // animate image array
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     //  [self animationEnded];
                 }
 ];
```

but I am not sure what to put where I have // animate image array

Answer (score -2):

Maybe [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self] will help you?

[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)]; will perform your animationDidStop:: then.

Or, if you are trying to stick with blocks, I think it would be a series of nested animations-complete sections like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     // Show first image
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // Hide first image
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
                     // Show second image
                    }
                    completion:^{
                        // Hide second image
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: So how Do I use     [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDiddStop:finished:context:)];   Because all I really want is to be able to call a method when a specific animation ends.    Is it something like [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDiddStop:finished:context: myImageView )];???